# How to install easy_align.vim?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, vim, plugins

I have vi in my linux, moreover I have the file `easy_align.vim` in `~/.vim/plugin/`

But when I am opening vi using `vi <file-name>`. The alignment is not working.

Do I explicitly install `vim` as vi by default open vim .and vi comes with my machine.

Answer (score 0):

To install VIM editor in ubuntu use,

1) **to make sure you have the latest sources.list**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2) To install vim

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Also, Vim is pre-installed in Linux based OS. For Ubuntu it minimal version is pre-installed.

```
vim.tiny
```

You can create alias to run it as vim

```
alias vim=vim.tiny
```

To make that alias permanent,

Add `"alias vim=vim.tiny"` line in `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: now I have installed vim.Will the plugin will work now or Do ineed to update it??

Comment: It will work if you have added it properly .. follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639606/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-vim

Comment: Ho wDo i add it to my vim??

Comment: extract the plugin tar into ~/vim/plugin or better way use "Plugin manager" https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug